# Python new file option missing from VS Code "New File..."

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have been using VS Code for around a month or so and the "New File..." option was giving the new Python file option until today when it randomly stopped. [See this image for context.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQSj6.png)

This is quite annoying as I now have to create a text file and end the name in .py rather than it appending .py by itself.

For context, I am using an Intel MacBook Pro from 2018.

Comment: I don't use VS Code much. Is there an addon you downloaded to work with python?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I have the extension and the OP is correct.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes, I downloaded the Python extension

Comment: maybe there was an update to the extension that removed this option. If you can find the github for it, you should ask there if this is an intended change or if they will fix it.

Comment: Try rolling back the vscode version to [`1.69.2`](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_69).

Answer (score 0):

Select File > New File > Text File (Built-in)

Then, on the first line of the newly created file, click Select a Language, then scroll down the list, and finally select Python.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/19952 shows that this was a deliberate decision by the developers of the python extension, which has since been rolled back. You can use the pre-release version to get it. (If in future it gets removed again, you can use a version of the extension before all of this happened)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).